# Hiding row of table when it is dragging using jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working in jquery drag and drop on a table, When I research for that I found a below working fiddle, Its working fine, But my requirement is I need to hide the row once it started to drag and need to display only when it dropped. How can I achieve this?

```
$("tbody").sortable({
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcoomey/Vn5SZ/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hide the clone on start event

```
$("tbody").sortable({
    items: "> tr:not(:first)",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(e, ui){
        ui.helper.hide()
    }
}).disableSelection();
```